# Unable to backup data on DVD

Tags: ubuntu, backup, dvd, data-cd

I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04.

I want to make backup of my data on DVD but unable to do so. To test this I'm backing up file name 'tomboy' from my current directory to DVD.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/Other$ dd if=./tomboy of=/dev/cdrom
dd: opening ‘/dev/cdrom’: Read-only file system
```

Then I ran the following intending to remount it as `read-write` mode.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/Other$ sudo mount -o rw,remount /dev/cdrom ~/Downloads
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/Other$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o rw,remount /dev/cdrom ~/Downloads
mount: /home/ravbholua/Downloads not mounted or bad option
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/Other$
```

I don't understand why it messaged above `mount: /home/ravbholua/Downloads not mounted or bad option`
Is my syntax wrong?
Then I tried the below:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/Other$ sudo umount /dev/cdrom
umount: /dev/cdrom: not mounted
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/Other$ sudo mount -t iso9660  /dev/cdrom ~/Downloads
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/Other$
```

I tried this with 2 DVDs but the same issue with both of them.

I need to back-up or copy data on a DVD & CD.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do this with `dd` and not use a normal CD burner?

Comment: Maybe do try `dmesg | tail` to see what's there, maybe a clue. Also, maybe `ls /dev` and look, maybe there's something else than _cdrom_ there...

Comment: @terdon I have SONY DVDs which aren't getting burned by a burner. I tried burning my Ubuntu 13.10 O.S. on it. The thread for this issue of burning is [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106895/error-while-burning-dvd?noredirect=1#comment164093_106895). As the SONY DVDs aren't getting burned, I want to use it to copy photoes and videos. so, I'm using `dd` command.

Comment: If the burner is not working, then neither will `dd`. IN any case, you can't do this directly with `dd`, you will need `mkisofs` and `cdparanoia` or whatever the equivalent is for DVDs. I recommend you forget about `dd` and focus on why the disks are not recognized by your burner.

Comment: @terdon the problem is with these DVDs. Amkette DVD & SONY DVDs which I purchased earlier worked perfectly. So these SONY DVDs which aren't working may be duplicate. Please have a look at my comment on [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106969/how-to-know-file-system-of-any-medium-like-hard-disk-cd-dvd-flash-drive?noredirect=1#comment164246_106969) thread. There I have mentioned that I ran a command to check f.s. on DVDs. The command ran on working DVDs but gave error "/dev/sr0: ERROR: cannot read `/dev/sr0' (Input/output error)" when I ran on these SONY DVDs which aren't working.

Comment: I know, that's exactly what I'm saying. The issue is with your DVDs, `dd` won't help.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just write on CD/DVD.
This would be your tool for DVD http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/growisofs1.html and this is for CD http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/writing-iso-images-cd-cdrecord

From growisofs man-page:

```
       To master and burn an ISO9660 volume with Joliet and Rock-Ridge  exten-
       sions on a DVD:

            growisofs -Z /dev/dvd -R -J /some/files

       To append more data to same DVD:

            growisofs -M /dev/dvd -R -J /more/files
```