# Error while burning DVD

Tags: ubuntu, burning

I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04. I purchased a few DVDs of Sony company from a few different shops but it failed to burn all these. Earlier I had used the Sony DVD only to burn the same date & it worked. I don't know why now none are working. But now the same data which didn't burn on Sony DVD was burned successfully on Amkette CD. I used Brasero disc burner. So, the problem seems to be of Sony DVD only.

Below is the error log when I was burning Ubuntu 13.10 O.S. on Sony DVD.

```
Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_6MF87W.bin toc = none
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI no burn:// URI found
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_OVE87W.bin toc = none
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack no remote URIs
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_U7D87W.bin toc = none
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Starting checksuming file /home/ravbholua/Documents/Other/special/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso (size = 938475520)
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Setting new checksum (type = 2) d0508f909c2c71d96aeac5efb0329b33 ((null) before)
BraseroChecksumImage Finished track successfully
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn unsupported operation
BraseroLibburn deactivating
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_device
BraseroLibburn Drive (/dev/sr0) init result = 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_media
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_tracks
BraseroLibburn Setting multi 0
BraseroLibburn Setting burnproof 1
BraseroLibburn Setting dummy 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_convert_fs_adr( /dev/sr0 )
BraseroLibburn Writing
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_is_enumerable_adr( /dev/sr0 ) is true
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Async START UNIT succeeded after 0.1 seconds
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn mmc_set_streaming: end_lba=2298495 ,  r=11080 ,  w=11080
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Allocating buffer via mmap()
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn dvd/bd Profile= 11h , obs= 32768 , obs_pad= 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn DVD pre-track 01 : get_nwa(0), ret= 1 , d->nwa= 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): See MMC specs: Sense Key 4 "Drive error", ASC 44 ASCQ D9.
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Libburn reported an error SCSI error on write(784,16): See MMC specs: Sense Key 4 "Drive error", ASC 44 ASCQ D9.
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 1
    message = "SCSI error on write(784,16): See MMC specs: Sense Key 4 "Drive error", ASC 44 ASCQ D9."
BraseroLibburn stopping
Session error : SCSI error on write(784,16): See MMC specs: Sense Key 4 "Drive error", ASC 44 ASCQ D9. (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

Comment: What kind of DVDs? I assume they are rewritable but are they DVD+RW? DVD-RW-? DVD±R? What types does your drive support?

Comment: From a very personal experience, RW is a recipe for losing data. Generally I'd recommend Verbatim CD/DVD only and I've had the most success burning stuff with k3b which you can try from the repositories(but that will install kdelibs and all). In any case you do need to disclose the type of DVD and to validate the compatibility of your drive as suggested...

Comment: Btw on Ubuntu there is the `lshw` tool which gives lots of detail on your hardware, which might be useful here!

Comment: @terdon the DVDs are mentioned as `DVD-R`. My drive of laptop supports ReWritable. On my laptop drive, its mentioned `rw` & `ReWritable`.

Comment: OK, make sure that `sudo lshw | grep DVD` returns a line that looks like `product: DVD+-RW`, perhaps your drive cannot deal with DVD-R.

Comment: @terdon my drive can deal perfectly with DVD-R types as earlier whatever DVDs I had burned were all the same type. The output of the command you told is: `description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD-RW DVRKD08RS`

Comment: Ah, OK, it is also possible you simply got a bad batch of DVDs. Since you can burn other DVDs of the same type with no issue, that seems the most likely explanation.

Comment: @terdon what about the output of the command I sent you in last comment. What it means! Does it indicate that my drive can deal with DVD-R?

Comment: Looks that way yes. It says `DVD-RW` so it should be able to work with `DVD-R`.

Comment: Sense key 4 is ‘hardware error’ and ASC 44 is ‘Internal Target Failure’. Note that these aren't medium errors (sense key 3). My SCSI is very rusty, and I suspect it's down to the DVD drive's firmware, but this may be a pure hardware error (drive about to depart the confines of this vain world), or a hardware error caused by the medium itself. As others said, this is down to a bad batch of DVDs, or your drive doesn't like that particular make of DVD. This used to happen a lot in Ye Olden Days. Some drives are just sensitive to media quality, and get more sensitive as they age.